# Dump contents of a variable inside a filter/hook callback that runs during save post

Tags: filters, debug

I just need to debug an array which comes into addfilter function like this:

```
add_filter('pll_copy_post_metas', 'copy_post_metas');
function copy_post_metas($metas) {
    var_dump($metas);
    return $metas;
}
```

How can I do that to just check what is the value of $metas?

This filter runs in admin when saving a post.

Comment: The above is not a hook that comes with wordpress must be some from a plugin, and if this exist then you are doing the right thing to debug it using the **var_dump** function.

Comment: Yes that is a plugin hook. Looks like I found the solution which suits me in this case: adding die after var_dump. Is there something else somebody would like to add for me to take into consideration?

Comment: The filter probably runs in the background, so if you don't stop the function using die(), the var_dump still works, you just can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a post, then you are basically submitting a big `<form>`. This form has an action pointing somewhere. Now there are two possibilities how the form is processed:

1. AJAX (background reload)
2. Default `<form>` handling (new request)

Basic form submitting is adding a new request (2), so the data gets processed and then the page reloads - that's the reason why you can't see the dump contents. Adding `exit` or `die` inside your callback (preferably after the `var_dump/var_export/print_r`), will stop the process and let you inspect the data.

If you are processing the data via AJAX (1), you will have to open your browsers developer tools (developer toolbar - Chrome, Firebug - FireFox, etc.) and look at the console/terminal. There you normally find a link when the AJAX request gets processed. This will lead you to the "network" (or similar) tab where you can inspect the request (headers, etc.) as well as a preview and/or the raw response. In there you will see the dumped data.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm in a testing environment that I control (and therefore not too worried about security) I will sometimes save the entire `$_POST` to an option (or you could do post meta)... that way you can `var_dump()` it later. Like you, I wanted to see what was being sent to the `save_post` hook, but didn't think to use a `die()` statement to stop the process.

```
function wpa_144460_var_dump( $post_id ){
   update_option( 'kia_testing', $_POST );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpa_144460_var_dump' );
```

Then you can view the data anywhere with:

```
var_dump( get_option( 'kia_testing' ) );
```